# View or Function to sum column time intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table and I would like to be able to sum (by selecting START_TIME, END_TIME and STATE) how long the STATE has been in that state.

```
    START_TIME          | END_TIME                  | DATA_VALUE
2023-05-26 17:53:09.997 |   2023-05-26 17:59:30.753 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:47:09.653 |   2023-05-26 17:59:31.033 |   STORIC
2023-05-26 17:45:05.237 |   2023-05-26 17:59:27.080 |   STORIC
2023-05-26 17:45:00.220 |   2023-05-26 17:45:05.237 |   OLD
2023-05-26 17:43:54.043 |   2023-05-26 17:53:09.997 |   OLD
2023-05-26 17:43:15.403 |   2023-05-26 17:59:27.597 |   OLD
2023-05-26 17:42:59.153 |   2023-05-26 17:47:09.653 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:41:53.990 |   2023-05-26 17:42:59.153 |   STORIC
2023-05-26 17:41:20.957 |   2023-05-26 17:43:15.403 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:40:44.707 |   2023-05-26 17:45:00.220 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:40:39.673 |   2023-05-26 17:40:44.707 |   STOPPED
2023-05-26 17:40:29.660 |   2023-05-26 17:40:39.673 |   OLD
2023-05-26 17:37:59.427 |   2023-05-26 17:40:29.660 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:35:53.170 |   2023-05-26 17:43:54.043 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:34:38.043 |   2023-05-26 17:35:53.170 |   OLD
2023-05-26 17:34:28.217 |   2023-05-26 17:41:53.990 |   MODERN
2023-05-26 17:29:47.813 |   2023-05-26 17:34:28.217 |   STORIC
2023-05-26 17:24:43.710 |   2023-05-26 17:59:27.863 |   STOPPED
2023-05-26 17:23:08.550 |   2023-05-26 17:24:43.710 |   MODERN
```

Comment: Your question could use some clarification. By "State" are you referring to DATA_VALUE? Your rows have overlapping date/time ranges, including some with the same DATA_VALUE. Should they be summed independent of one another? For example, the second and third rows have durations of approximately 00:12:22 and 00:14:22 with 00:12:18 of overlap. Would you expect a sum duration of 00:26:44 or 00:14:26? If overlaps matter, does that include those with different DATA_VALUEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some test data:

```
DECLARE @testData table (start_time datetime, end_time datetime, data_value varchar(20));
 INSERT INTO @testData (start_time, end_time, data_value)
 VALUES ('2023-05-26 17:53:09.997', '2023-05-26 17:59:30.753', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:47:09.653', '2023-05-26 17:59:31.033', 'STORIC')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:45:05.237', '2023-05-26 17:59:27.080', 'STORIC')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:45:00.220', '2023-05-26 17:45:05.237', 'OLD')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:43:54.043', '2023-05-26 17:53:09.997', 'OLD')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:43:15.403', '2023-05-26 17:59:27.597', 'OLD')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:42:59.153', '2023-05-26 17:47:09.653', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:41:53.990', '2023-05-26 17:42:59.153', 'STORIC')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:41:20.957', '2023-05-26 17:43:15.403', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:40:44.707', '2023-05-26 17:45:00.220', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:40:39.673', '2023-05-26 17:40:44.707', 'STOPPED')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:40:29.660', '2023-05-26 17:40:39.673', 'OLD')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:37:59.427', '2023-05-26 17:40:29.660', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:35:53.170', '2023-05-26 17:43:54.043', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:34:38.043', '2023-05-26 17:35:53.170', 'OLD')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:34:28.217', '2023-05-26 17:41:53.990', 'MODERN')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:29:47.813', '2023-05-26 17:34:28.217', 'STORIC')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:24:43.710', '2023-05-26 17:59:27.863', 'STOPPED')
      , ('2023-05-26 17:23:08.550', '2023-05-26 17:24:43.710', 'MODERN');
```

Here is one possible solution:

```
DECLARE @start_date datetime    = '2023-05-26 17:59:00.000'
      , @end_date   datetime    = '2023-05-26 17:59:59.997'
      , @state      varchar(20) = 'MODERN';

 SELECT *
      , Duration = datediff(MILLISECOND, dt.start_time, dt.end_time)
   FROM @testData               td
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (iif(td.start_time < @start_date, @start_date, td.start_time)
                     , iif(td.end_time > @end_date, @end_date, td.end_time)))            dt(start_time, end_time)
  WHERE td.data_value =  @state
    AND dt.start_time <= dt.end_time;
```

Given the above - you can GROUP BY and SUM as needed.

Comment: Note: if you do have spans that are too large, just change it to use DATEDIFF_BIG instead.

Comment: I need seconds, so DATEDIFF is enough. Extraordinary answer that completely solves the question: simple and elegant!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer in milliseconds:

```
SELECT Data_Value, SUM(DateDiff(millisecond, Start_Time, End_Time))
FROM [MyTable] t
GROUP BY Data_Value
```

You can work from there how to format this value as something more helpful
(hint: [`TimeFromParts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

Be aware: if you have cumulative lengths that get up around 27 days you can start to have integer overflow issues. But if things are running that long, its likely millisecond precision also no longer matters as much, and you change the `DATEDIFF()` call to use seconds instead.

Comment: Thank you Joel. However, my problem arises when I want to select a precise date/time interval. Consider moreover that this cannot not necessarily match exactly with the values ​​I have in the table.  So if i want an interval that starts at 2023-05-26 17:59:00.000 we should consider that the first MODERN value shoud be summed only for 30.753seconds.

Comment: This is a new requirement. You should edit the question to better explain this need, but most likely you can solve this with an additional `WHERE` clause and a `CASE` expression inside the `DATEDIFF()` call to choose the right `Start_Time`.

Comment: Your solution is too obvious while my question is very clear!
Can you answer or not?